# ensureIndex asks for callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to create an index in MongoDB to store unique slugs.

I use this code to generate the index:

```
this._db = db;
this._collection = this._db.collection("Topics");
this._collection.ensureIndex( { slug: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

But when I run my tests it fails on the "beforeEach": (I'm using mongo-clean NPM)

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    clean(dbURI, function (err, created) {
        db = created;
        instance = topicManager(db);
        done(err);
    });
});
```

Saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback
```

What am I doing wrong? (if I comment the ensureIndex everything works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the response implies, you might need to provide a callback function to your call to `ensureIndex`:

```
this._db = db;
this._collection = this._db.collection("Topics");
this._collection.ensureIndex( { slug: 1 }, { unique: true }, function(error) {
  if (error) {
   // oops!
  }});
```

Comment: Can't I handle it during the insert?

Comment: The callback function is not used for handling future operations to the database, but to ensure that the index was successfully created. When inserting new documents, you are also expected to provide callback functions.

Comment: Ok but if I want to try to insert something and in case I get an error because the slug is not unique I want to change the slug and try again how can I do? I thought it was possible with unique indexes

Comment: Indeed, you can do that with a callback function: if an insert operation fails with error code 11000, it means a duplicate key collision occurred. See an example log: http://pastebin.com/KPmYxZvw

Comment: Ok... If I add a callback my insert returns, beside the element I've inserted, a `[Error: Connection was destroyed by application]`. Without ensureIndex I don't get this...

Comment: That sounds like a distinct issue from what you are trying to solve with this question. Try updating it with the problems that you currently have.

Comment: I've opened a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477420/ensureindex-causes-error

Answer (score 2):

**`ensueIndex()` is now deprecated in v^3.0.0**

For those who use `^3.0.0`:

> Deprecated since version 3.0.0: db.collection.ensureIndex() is now an alias for db.collection.createIndex().

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique

Example:

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```